# What is the smallest font size for print css?

Tags: html, css, printing

I have a table of HTML5. When I change the font-size below 8pt, it does not look like smaller than 8pt in the browser. Because I just want smaller font in printing, will it take effect to the printing when I set the font size to 6pt or smaller?

Comment: Print it out and find out? That's awfully small... "small print".

Comment: Could you provide your code? I can't reproduce the "8pt" limit. Also, the limit depends on your printer, you'll send data and the printer decides if he can print that or not.